How to pull every H2 with unique ID inside a div block than have an active state?
I got this code from an article that pull every h2 into table of content, where u can easily navigate on the page. The unique IDs are created using the value 'i'.
Now I wanted to have the h2 insde a block that also with have active state element (refer photo for reference).


  document.getElementById("content").querySelectorAll("h2").forEach(function(heading, i) { // runs a function for all h2 elements inside your rich text element
    heading.setAttribute("id", "toc-" + i); // gives each h2 a unique id
    observer.observe(heading);
    let str = heading.innerHTML; // adds section titles to slugs
    str = str.replace(/\s+/g, '-').replace(/[°&\/\\#,+()$~%.'":;*?<>{}]/g, "").toLowerCase(); // replaces spaces with hyphens, removes special characters and extra spaces from the headings, and applies lowercase in slugs
    heading.setAttribute("id", str); // gives each heading a unique id
    const item = document.createElement("a"); // creates an anchor element called "item" for each h2
    item.innerHTML = heading.innerHTML // gives each item the text of the corresponding heading
    item.setAttribute("class", "tocitem"); // gives each item the correct class
    item.setAttribute("href", "#" + str); // gives each item the correct anchor link
    document.querySelector("#toc").appendChild(item); // places each item inside the Table of Contents div
  });




Never create indexed ids, they're error prone and a nightmare to maintain.
